# List files built by TypeScript depending on current tsconfig

Tags: typescript, next.js

I have trouble managing multiple tsconfig in my application, which I need to manage unit tests and stories collocated to code (see [this issue in Next for instance](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/23972)).

Main problem is that I cannot debug the files that will actually be used depending on `tsconfig.json`, and exclusion/inclusion rules are not always obvious in particular when having extended `tsconfig` and configs nested into folder.

Example:

The common config `tsconfig.common.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": false,
    "target": "es5",
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"]
}
```

The main config `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.common.json",
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.stories.tsx",
    "**/stories.tsx",
    "**/*.test.ts",
    "**/*.tests.ts",
    "cypress"
  ],
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx"]
}
```

The nested config `src/tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.common.json",
  "include": ["**/*.tsx", "**/*.ts"]
}
```

So, given a project, can I tell which files are included in TypeScript build for a given `tsconfig.json` or at least the main one?